# Why does my app crash if I don't set in the SQL table not null statement?

Tags: android, sqlite

**I have this code:**

```
{

    String SQL_CREATE_BOOKS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + BooksContract.BooksEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRODUCT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRICE + " DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_QUANTITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_SUPPLIER + " TEXT, "
                + BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PHONE + " INTEGER );";
          db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_BOOKS_TABLE);
}
```

Even though I didn't set the supplier to be `not null`, if I don't type it in my `editText` when I click the save button my app crashes. Also even though quantity is set to default 0, if I don't type any quantity it still crashes. why?

**EditorActivity:**

```
 private void insertBooks() {

        String productString = productName.getText().toString().trim();
        String priceString = price.getText().toString().trim();
        int price = Integer.parseInt(priceString);
        String quantityString = quantity.getText().toString().trim();
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);
        String supplierString = supplier.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneString = supplierPhone.getText().toString().trim();
        int phone = Integer.parseInt(phoneString);
        BooksDbHelper dbHelper = new BooksDbHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRODUCT, productString);
        values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRICE, priceString);
        values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_QUANTITY, quantityString);
        values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_SUPPLIER, supplierString);
        values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PHONE, phoneString);

        long newRowId = db.insert(BooksContract.BooksEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);


        if (newRowId == -1) {
            // If the row ID is -1, then there was an error with insertion.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Book saved with row id: " + newRowId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**CatalogActivity:**

```
private void insertBooks() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRODUCT, "Walks with men");
    values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PRICE, 10.00);
    values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_QUANTITY, 2);
    values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_SUPPLIER, "Amazon");
    values.put(BooksContract.BooksEntry.COLUMN_BOOKS_PHONE, 727213658);

    long newRowId = db.insert(BooksContract.BooksEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error

Comment: You probably just trying to parse a integer from a empty text, this results on NumberFormatException, this case just check if empty or not a number before parsing

Comment: i am sorry my mistake.it is text not integer.it should be able to save if i didn't type the supplier wright?

Comment: Post the code that you use to save the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your `insertBooks()` method to avoid `NumberFormatException`:

```
String productString = productName.getText().toString().trim();

String priceString = price.getText().toString().trim();
double price = 0.0;
try {
    price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String quantityString = quantity.getText().toString().trim();
int quantity = 0;
try {
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String supplierString = supplier.getText().toString().trim();

String phoneString = supplierPhone.getText().toString().trim();
```

Why is phone INTEGER?

**Note:**
The create table code you posted is probably part of the `onCreate()` method in your class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  
The `onCreate()` method was executed the 1st time you ran the app and created the table.  
 Since then you may have altered the columns either by type or name, or even inserted or deleted columns, but all these changes were made **only in your code and not in the table**. The onCreate() method has never again been triggered.  
So if any of the above applies to you:  
Uninstall the app from the emulator/device so that the database is deleted and run again your app to recreate it as it should be.

Comment: i have the table created in BooksDphelper.here is my project. Also when i edit a new book if i dont complete all editTexts the app crashes.i now i have to use something like if(TextUtils.isEmpty(productString)) {
    productString.setError("Your message");
    return;
 } but i dont know where to put it.  https://github.com/RoxanaG/InventoryApp.git

Comment: post the crash log

Comment: i deleted my app again and now the supplier is ok but the same problem occurs with the phone number.here is my log error  08-02 10:05:24.474 3655-3655/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.grasu.inventoryapp-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied

Comment: @Prox make the phone number TEXT not INTEGER. It is a field that will never be used in any calculations. Uninstall the app and run it again. I will change the above code in a min